# AJAX - save an $_FILES picture in media library

Tags: images, ajax, media-library

From an array like this

`Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => 100522738.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpv9nkXY [error] => 0 [size] => 41784 ) )`

What is the best way to import the temp file into the wp media library ?

media_sideload_image() ? but how ?

Comment: See the Codex example for [`media_handle_sideload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_sideload/#comment-983) and [`media_handle_upload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/#comment-534) - use the latter if your array comes from an actual form submission.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thanks a lot, exactly what i needed !!! i didn't know that function.. we learn every day. thaks for sharing !